# Working with an image height and width using only the image URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I'm working with react and I'm trying to get the height and width from an image from which I only have the url. This is what I have so far:

```
const testImg = new Image();
let a; let b;

testImg.addEventListener("load", function(){
console.log("1. Properties " + testImg.width + " " + testImg.height);
a = testImg.width;
b = testImg.height;
});

testImg.src = thumbUrl;

console.log("2. Properties " + testImg.width + " " + testImg.height);
console.log("3. Properties " + a + " " + b);
```

The output of the first "properties" log is  correct (336 & 223 pixels). The output of the second is 0 & 0 and the output of the third is undefined & undefined.

I have tried puting the "testImg.src = thumbUrl" line before the onload function and the outputs are the same. I need to use these values outside that function. Also have tried using the decode function.

If you have any other approach or a solution for this I'd appreciate that very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call - this one is about AJAX requests, but the underlying problem of asynchronicity is the same here.

Comment: The better approach is to simulate an image loading with fixed width/height then after `loaded` update the width/height. The Event is trigger after 2. and 3.

Comment: Pure JS: https://jsfiddle.net/3cnbh7jq/

Comment: Is there anyway I can work with this, without the using the DOM part? Something like throw the loading of the image in a async function? I tried that but it seems that I didnt do it properly

Comment: can't you just run the code that needs to use those dimensions in the onload?